# How to turn a text pdf into picture pdf?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

**How to transform a pdf with text into a "picture pdf", that is, a pdf based on pictures in one single command?**

I can obviously run multiple commands to do it but I am sure there is a straightest way to do it (with `convert` and `pdftk` for instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using `convert`](https://askubuntu.com/a/50173/158442) seems to do the trick:

```
convert -density 150 input.pdf -quality 90 output.pdf
```

Comment: I can confirm it does.