# How to secure .pdf file to prevent cut and paste from terminal command line

Tags: macos, pdftk

The goal is to prevent recipients from cutting and pasting text content.  All recipients shall have access: there should not be a password obstacle to prevent opening the document.

I do not know what the corresponding keyword to Google a solution.

Solutions that utilize pdftk or other terminal commands are preferred / appreciated.

How can said goals be achieved?

Comment: I think you would have to convert the pdf text to images.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings Please consider posting an answer with a concrete example.  Thank you

Comment: you can't.  If people can see it, they can copy it.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings Does [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/352801/182280) capture your idea?

Comment: @gatorback yes, anything that converts a pdf text doc to a pdf image doc will do the job.

Comment: Even if you convert it to an image, people can still copy the text from it using e.g. [TextSnatcher](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/02/textsnatcher-copy-text-from-images-linux) and if they're on a m1 Mac, [support is built directly into the os](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-live-text-copy-share-text-images-mac/).